# APM Open source : Angular + Java Spring + Postgresql

Tags: performance, monitoring, apm

I need to monitor my backend cpu, memory and disk usage (java spring web app + potsgresql)

I am looking for a truly free APM (no time limit), easy to install (java + db), easy to use, nice dashboards etc...

I only need to monitor my java web app and one postgresql db